# How to specify the arrangement position of multiple buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am tkinter noob. I'm rewriting my own program using other people's examples. But what I am confused about is that I don’t know how to place the buttons where I want. Can someone please advise? Or where can I refer from? Many thank.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Test Windows")
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '1000x600')
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        Graph_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        Graph_btn.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        BtH_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        BtH_btn.pack(side='left')
        
        BtH_btn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home2")
        BtH_btn2.pack(side='left')

        f = Figure(figsize=(10,3), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

I want the button to be horizontally below the `label`.
[image]

Comment: Put the 2 buttons in a frame. Then you can use `<your frame>.pack()` and then `canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill="both", expand=True)`

Comment: I don't get it, BtH_btn.pack(side='top') instead of BtH_btn.pack(side='left') (same for BtH_btn2.pack(side='left') ) doesn't work ? You absolutely want it inside the plot's canvas ?

Comment: @TheLizzard, thank your reply, as you said, I need to add frames. I was too obsessed with setting the `init` of `Application` before, but everything works after setting in `PageTwo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 different routes, you can either use :

- widget.pack() : it's useful for small things but I don't use it much I prefer:
- widget.grid(column = x, row = y) : you can even tell the rowspan and columnspan eventually. No overlapping.
- widget.place(x, y) : It places your widget at the exact position given. Just remember it will depend on your window size whether or not it will be placed correctly and on the size of the widget itself (can overlap).

In your example, I'll use the grid method.

[This link](https://zetcode.com/tkinter/layout/) provides a deeper explanation and a good example.

Comment: If OP is to use `.grid` instead of `.pack`, you will need to post a link to an explanation of how to make the canvas expand to fill the window.

Comment: @Apo, thank for your much input, I am not familiar with `grid` yet, adding frame is more understandable for me.